# Remote Grid filter in gxt 2.2.5.I am not able to perform remote filtering on gxt grid

Tags: grid, gxt

```
StringFilter reportNameFilter=new StringFilter("reportName");
    StringFilter categoryFilter=new StringFilter("category");

    GridFilters gridFilters=new GridFilters();
    gridFilters.setLocal(true);

    gridFilters.addFilter(categoryFilter);
    gridFilters.addFilter(reportNameFilter);

    grid = new Grid<BeanModel>(store, columns);
    grid.setWidth(550);
    grid.setHeight(320);
    grid.setBorders(false);
    grid.setStripeRows(true);
    grid.setColumnLines(true);
    grid.addPlugin(gridFilters);
```

Comment: I have 10 pages filtering is happening on all pages ,but records are displaying on all pages.It must show all filtered data in single page.Gxt version 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

We can override Events.Deactivate and Events.Activate for the grid filters.
And reconfigure grid with page size,BasePagingLoader

`pagingToolBar.setPageSize(getReportNames().size());
      pagingToolBar.bind(loader);
      loader.load(0, getReportNames().size() );
      tempProxy  = new PagingModelMemoryProxy(store.getModels());
      tempLoader  = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<BeanModel>>(tempProxy);
      tempLoader.setRemoteSort(true);
      tempStore = new ListStore<BeanModel>(tempLoader);
pagingToolBar.setPageSize(Integer.parseInt(listbox.getValue(listbox.getSelectedIndex())));
      pagingToolBar.bind(tempLoader);

      tempLoader.load(0, Integer.parseInt(listbox.getValue(listbox.getSelectedIndex())));
      grid.reconfigure(tempStore, buildColumnModel());
      pagingToolBar.refresh();`